# How to loop a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am not sure if loop is the right term,  but I have a products page that is working perfectly. I want to be able to have an " Add product option button" that when the admin clicks on it, it toggles down and another "Add products option button" replaces the one i just opened. So the number of products options is unlimited, the user will be able to add as many products as they like.

```
        <!--Restaurant toggle-->
        <a id="restt" class ="header"href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');">
            <h3 id="open">Your Restaurants</h3>
        </a>
        <div id="Rest" class="Rest_new" style="display: none;"><div>
        <ul class="tabs1">
            <!--                    
            <li id="order" class="rred">
                <a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">restaurant</a>
            </li>
            -->
            <li id="order_open" class="rgreen">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">New restaurant</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- add element-->
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'li#order_open', function() {
        $(this).before('<li><a href="Menu.php">New restaurant</a></li>');

        // add to localsorage? 
        window.onload = function() {} 
        var order_open = $('div#Rest').html();
        localStorage.setItem('div#Rest', order_open);
    });
</script>
```

I am using the following code at the moment. It creates unlimited options however, i can not open the options, i cannot make it toggle and it disappears on page refresh. Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Its not a php, but javascript question. It can be easily done with jquery

Comment: What is it you are expecting to happen? Why are you using local storage?

Comment: I was trying to use local storage, to store and then later retrieve the data but it doesn't seem like it is working

Answer (score 1):

You question is javascript. You could use

```
$('container').append('html content');
```

See an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
```

See more
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Comment: Thank you very helpful. A mixture of two of the answers done the trick. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To create additional restaurants, you can use jQuery's append function to add the link.  Then use localstorage to store and retrieve the number of links created.

**HTML**

```
<h3 id="open">Your Restaurants</h3>
<div class="Rest_new" id="rest">
<div>
    <ul class="tabs1" id="optionContainer">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScrtipt**

```
var options = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('numberOfOptions'));
if(isNaN(options)) { options = 0; }


function addOption(n) {
    $('#optionContainer').append('<li class="rgreen" id="order_open'+n+'"><a href="javascript:void(0);">New restaurant '+n+'</a></li>');
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < options; i++) {
        addOption(i);
    }

    $('#open').on('click',function() {
    addOption(options);
    options++;
    localStorage.setItem('numberOfOptions',parseInt(options));
  })

});
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/pm4Lv44t/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very helpful. A mixture of two of the answers done the trick. much appreciated.